# Visual Studio 2017 debug freezes and aborts when calling DateTime.Now;

Tags: c#, datetime, debugging, visual-studio-2017

When in debugging, whenever I try to get a DateTime value in any way, such as:

```
camLogMessage.MsgDateTime = DateTime.Now;

if (myObj.Date < DateTime.Now.Date){}

DateTime creation = File.GetCreationTime(@"C:\test.txt");
```

Visual Studio freezes for a few seconds, then states that

> The network connection to MYCOMPUTER has been lost. Debugging will be
>   aborted.

and so it does.

If I set a property to a DateTime value in a QuickWatch window, everything goes well.

VS2017, .Net Framework 4.6.2, Platform target x64. 
I'm not using remote debugging, as far as I know.

What can that be?

Comment: You are using the remote debugger, VS is a 32-bit process.  You need to get this machine healthy again.  That usually starts by disabling the installed anti-malware product.  Or use another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, disabling ReSharper fixed my problem. I don't know what combination of settings caused that (I've been using it for years with no problems), but I think it's time to say goodbye to RS.